# how can i set background image(texture) for epub reader webview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiwebview, epub

i wanna show a texture for my epub reader uiwebview.i done this before but now iam not able to re create that code again.

i know that whatever code we have to add should add it in webviewdidfinishload method

```
     - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)thewebView{
      if(texture==1) {  
             webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"darkWoodP.png"]];

 }
    .....



    }
```

but this only working for one single html (chapter)i need it for all html files.epub may contains 5 to 100 html files..pleaes help me

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue,

What i done is

First i create a global flag in my tableviewcell
`flag=1`  means   woodcolor texture
`flag=2`  means   lightcolor texture

in didselectmethode

```
if (indexpath.row==1) {
    flag=1;
    [self texturemethode];
} else if (indexpath.row==2) {
    flag=2;
    [self texturemethode];
}
```

inside texturemethode method

```
-(void)texturemethode {
    if (flag==1) {
        webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.png"]];
    } else if (flag==2) {
        webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light.png"]];
    }
}
```

in webviewDidFinishLoad method

am again checking this

```
if (flag==1) {
    webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.png"]];
} else if (flag==2) {
    webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light.png"]];
}
```

now it will work